# How to use Wolfram to draw Cantor function?

Tags: wolfram-alpha, cantor-set

I want to have a close look on the image of $\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{2}$ Cantor function, which is a rigidly increasing one.
I look up in the Wolfram and it told me it has a symbol called CantorStaircase to draw the image of Cantor function, but when I calculate it, it just don't work. What should I do? What's the problem?
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CantorStaircase.html

[image]

Comment: Just so you know, there is a dedicated [Stack Exchange site for Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Wojowu, the question would be welcome there if this is about plotting it in *Mathematica*; if the OP was asking how to do this in Alpha, it would be off-topic. (Disclosure: I mod mathematica.SE.)